# Coronation Treat? A sign o' the times?

Tags: wordplay

The three overlapping ellipses form seven curved regions. Can you place the tiles so that exactly one tile is in each region and for each ellipse the tiles therein can be re-arranged to form an eight-letter solution to the corresponding clue?

This week - perplexing politics!

[image: 1]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> [image]

Egalitarian:

> POPULIST

Perplexing:

> PUZZLING

Chomsky:

> LINGUIST